# date not in title page, can't find isodate package

Tags: datetime, isodate

Between begin and end titlepage, I use `\date{\today}`. C-c C-c does not complain, but no date shows up. I saw another guy using `isodate`, but I don't have that package. On `aptitude search ~n^texlive`, there seems to be nothing date-related (?).

Comment: What compilation system are you using? I usually don't put anything in `\date{}` (i.e. I don't issue the command) and both `pdflatex` and `xelatex` answers that by putting today's date on the title page. Are you sure you haven't modified the title page and removed a call to `\@thedate` (or whatever it's called internally)?

Comment: Hm, compilation system. I hit C-c C-c in LaTeX/P mode, then it uses the default command, which is LaTeX. Is that it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've just misunderstood slightly how `\date` works I think. The argument of `\date` is saved, and printed by  `\maketitle`. When you write `\date{\today}`, you say that `\maketitle` should print todays date (which it does by default, in the standard classes at least). To print todays date at a place of your choosing, just write `\today`.

`\maketitle` also prints the `\title` and `\author`. For example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\author{Some One}
\title{Whatnot}
\date{Tomorrow}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

Today is \today.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Right, `\today` works.