# Titling package and date formatting

Tags: titling, datetime2, isodate

I am using the *titling* package the resuse the defined date etc. using a plain `\thedate` command. However the date format is not what I need because of different type of localization.

My first shot was using *isodate* package using an appropriate option but this seems not to work with the *titling* package.

Anyway, here is what I created:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ngerman]{isodate}
\usepackage{titling}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\date{\today}

\begin{document}
typically this: \thedate \\
should be: \today \\
but it is: {\origdate\thedate} \\
not even: {\isodate\thedate} \\
\end{document}
```

**Clearification:** My intention is to reuse the defined date using `\date` with any apropriate tool. I came up using *titling* which works great for titles etc. but the date show formatting issues (`\today` and `\thedate` differ). Following a comment I tried to use the *datetime2* package, which does not seem to work using the date reference solution I use so far.

Here is a snippet using *datetime2* package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}
\usepackage{titling}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\date{\today}
%\DTMsavedate{date0}{\thedate} % does not compile
\DTMsavedate{date1}{2017-04-25}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}
%maybe this: \DTMdate{\thedate} \\ % neither does this
wait, what: \DTMusedate{date1} \\
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps the package datetime2 is a better option: see for example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/290204/112503

Comment: @IAtExFan My intenion was to reuse the defined date with `\date` and apply an appropriate format which does not work using the _datetime2_ package. I tried using `\DTMdate{\thedate}` and `\DTMsavedate{date}{\thedate}` but neither did work with the date reference. I might come up storing the date by hand as an solution though.

Comment: @maxit could you please give us an example input and the desired output? `german date: \DTMusedate{date1}\\
\selectlanguage{british}
british date: \DTMusedate{date1}\\
\selectlanguage{french}
french date: \DTMusedate{date1}` (seems ok for me, using: `\usepackage[ngerman,british,french]{babel}` of course)

Comment: @IAtExFaN The desired output has to have the same format as the `\today` command (for simplicity). I had it working too, please see the question edit for further information.

Comment: does this answer help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57613/112503

Comment: @IAtExFaN Yes, I had some misunderstanding on the `\date` command, which explains why my solution could not work I think. Anyway it does not explain why the formatting of `\thedate` differs from `\today` which is my main problem here. Following the provided link they should not, I think. It is simply text in both cases, or not?

Comment: please use \show\date \show\thedate and \show\today to see the differences (show's output is directed to the logfile)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your own converter.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ngerman]{isodate}
\usepackage{titling}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\date{\today}

\newcommand\convertdate[1]{\expandafter\convertdateaux#1\relax}
\def\convertdateaux#1 #2, #3\relax{#2.\@ #1 #3}

\begin{document}
typically this: \thedate \\
should be: \today \\
but it is: {\origdate\thedate} \\
not even: {\isodate\thedate} \\

How about \convertdate{\thedate}?
\end{document}
```

[image]